# Dolphin not showing activity and status for moving or copying files

Tags: dolphin

I am running Kubuntu 19.04. When I move or copy a large number of files, Dolphin does not display any indication of the progress nor completion.

Is there a setting I need to turn on?

Comment: You need to mention your operating system and version. Plus, proofread your post: what is "04 and" at the beginning of the question?

Comment: Thank you.... I am running Kbuntu 19.04.   when i move or copy a large number of files, Dolphin does not display any indication of the progress nor completion.

Comment: See https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=152785#p399772